# reshape function not mapping values correctly

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2, long-format-data

I am working with a within-subjects design looking at how participants rated 20 videos across a variety of variables (valence, arousal, etc.) and am trying to turn my wide-format df into a long format so it looks like this...

| ID | Video_Type | Valence | Arousal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Comedy | 1 | 100 |
| 123 | Drama | 4 | 82 |

Currently the wide-format looks something like this:

| ID | Comedy.valence | Comedy.arousal | Comedy.rating | Drama.valence | Drama.arousal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 1 | 1 | 100 | 5 | 7 |
| 999 | 6 | 4 | 82 | 3 | 8 |

When I use the code below all of the column names for the long dataset are correct but the values aren't mapping on correctly (e.g., the values for valence are placed under arousal, the values for arousal are placed under rating, etc.)

```
reshape(videoratings, direction = "long", 
        varying=c(1:23), 
        timevar = "video",
        times = c("Comedy", "Drama", "Action"),
        v.names = c("valence", "arousal", "rating"),
        idvar = "ResponseId")
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Which one is your input data.  If it is the second data as input, try `library(tidyr);pivot_longer(videoratings, cols = -ID, names_to = c("Video_Type", ".value"), names_sep = "\\.")`

Comment: Or with `reshape` `reshape(cbind(videoratings, Drama.rating = NA), idvar = "ID", varying = list(c(2,5), c(3,6), c(4, 7)), v.names = c("Valence", "Arousal", "Rating"), direction = "long", timevar = "Video_Type")`

Comment: Your names are specified the opposite way around for what `reshape` expects - the function wants "variable.time" not "time.variable".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to switch the names. This cannot be reversed using the `split =`  parameter hence use `sub` function

```
reshape(setNames(df, sub("(\\w+).(\\w+)","\\2.\\1", names(df))), -1, dir='long', idv = 'ID')

            ID   time valence arousal rating
111.Comedy 111 Comedy       1       1    100
999.Comedy 999 Comedy       6       4     82
111.Drama  111  Drama       5       7     20
999.Drama  999  Drama       3       8     80
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked - would you be able to explain how this fixed the problem so I know for next time? Thanks again!

Comment: @SamJones I just changed the ordering of the names, ie X.Y `X` becomes the column names and Y becames the values

Answer (score 1):

I created a sample dataset like your example

```r
df <- data.frame(ID=c(111,999), Comedy.valence=c(1, 6), Comedy.arousal=c(1,4), Comedy.rating=c(100,82), Drama.valence=c(5,3), Drama.arousal=c(7,8), Drama.rating=c(20,80))
```

Then, I applied reshape like the following:

```r
df2 <- reshape(df, varying = 2:7, direction = "long", idvar = "ID", timevar = "Video_Type", v.names = c("valence", "arousal", "rating"), times = c("Comedy", "Drama"))

row.names(df2) <- NULL

df2
```

And, the output looks like:

```
   ID Video_Type valence arousal rating
1 111     Comedy       1     100      1
2 999     Comedy       4      82      6
3 111      Drama       7      20      5
4 999      Drama       8      80      3
```

I modified my code a little more:

```r
df2 <- reshape(df, 
        varying = 2:7, 
        direction = "long", 
        idvar = "ID", 
        timevar = "Video_Type", 
        v.names = unlist(unique(lapply(strsplit(names(df), split="\\.")[2:7], '[[', 2))), 
        times = unlist(unique(lapply(strsplit(names(df), split="\\.")[2:7], '[[', 1))))

row.names(df2) <- NULL

df2
```

I guess it depends how many columns you have, you can modify the column index in the `varying` and `lapply`